# Get env variable from heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

I have django project on heroku.
On my Procfile i use 'release: bach./releast-tasks.sh' that will generate new env variable.

```
web: gunicorn billions.wsgi --log-file -
release: bash ./release-tasks.sh
```

Here my release-tasks.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
electrum daemon -d
electrum setconfig rpcport 7777
pass=$(electrum getconfig rpcpassword)
echo $pass
export RPCPASSWORD=$pass
```

The deploy (git push heroku master) is working fine and perfectly. I do not get any error.

But now on my code i try to get "RPCPASSWORD" env variable like that :

```
logger.info(os.environ.get('RPCPASSWORD', 'None'))
```

It's alaways returning None.

So 2 problems :

- I am not sure the env variable is really set with release-tasks.sh
- If it's correctly set, why i can't grab it with my django code :/ ?

Thank for your help !

Comment: That's now how you set an environment variable. You do it through the Heroku CLI (see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#managing-config-vars) or on the Settings page of your Heroku App. You can do something like: `web: bash ./release-tasks.sh && gunicorn billions.wsgi --log-file -`
The `release` process you defined isn't something that is automatically executed. It's a simple process you can start or stop.

Comment: Ok thank you a lot :) It's working well.
PS : support also answered me, i also have solution the solution to use API to config vars(link in the documentation you gave).